# property of conditional expectation.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

$X$ is a random variable in ($\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}$),$\mathcal{G,H}$ are two sub $\sigma$-algebra and $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ .
I don't know whether the following equality is true or not.(if not, I can add the condition that $\mathcal{G,H}$ are independent)

> $$\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G,H})=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{H})$$

In intuition,it seems to be true since $\mathcal{G}$ doesn't provide any information.Rigorously，it is sufficient to prove that  $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G,H})$ is $\mathcal{H}$-measurable.I am stuck in this step.Follow the definition of measurable,I want to analyze the structure of $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G,H})^{-1}(B)$ ($B\in\mathcal{H}$),I don't know what to do next.

---

The question above comes from Durrett's textbook http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf

page 226:example 5.6.1 using backwards martingales to prove the SLLN.
in the fifth line

> $$\mathbb{E}(\xi_j|\mathcal{F}_{-n-1})=\mathbb{E}(\xi_k|\mathcal{F}_{-n-1})$$

the author said it's true by symmetry but I want to prove it rigorously.
I know how to prove

> $$\mathbb{E}(\xi_j|S_{n+1})=\mathbb{E}(\xi_k|S_{n+1})$$

but I don't know how to prove

> $$\mathbb{E}(\xi_j|\mathcal{F}_{-n-1})=\mathbb{E}(\xi_j|S_{n+1})$$

Comment: You need $\sigma(X,\mathcal{H})$ to be independent of $\mathcal{G}$, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365310/conditional-expectation-on-more-than-one-sigma-algebra).

Comment: @StefanHansen thanks I will check it.

Comment: Please do not add a second completely unrelated question to your post.